# Angular.js Custom directive for comma separation and decimal value rounding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angula.js and i need to write a custom directive to

- Separate a number with commas based on thousand(1,27,222)
- if the no have floating points more than 2 then it should be rounded into 2(if value is 666.88888 then it should rounded like 666.89)
- A dollar sign ($) should add before the value.

The value/number is taking from the db(a parameter is passing in to the custom directive). I can use custom filter for the same purpose but in this case i'm forced to use custom directive.

let me do this by sharing your knowledge with me..

Answer (score 0):

http://embed.plnkr.co/8mT3EA/

This plunker has implemented the same . Go through it . Also go through the angular documentation for currency filter here -
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a custom directive since this is already present in Angular. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

```js
 angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('TestController', ['$scope',
     function($scope) {
       $scope.priceWithDec = 12345678.12565;
       $scope.priceWithoutDec = 12345678;
     }
   ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div>{{ priceWithDec | currency : '$' }}</div>
    <div>{{ priceWithoutDec | currency : '$' }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```